# Guitar Chord Detection

Tags: audio, detection, guitar, music-notation

While most of the other questions here are regarding determining how to know which notes comprise a chord, I am asking on a slightly different point.

How would you be able to determine whether a sound played is a single note, or a chord? Ive tried searching for some papers but so far, I have only seen papers tackling how to detect the notes of a chord rather than differentiating whether the sound produced was only a single note or a chord.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You would need to do some kind of pattern matching on the power spectrum. For a single note you will see the fundamental + multiple harmonics, all of which are at integer multiples of the fundamental frequency of course. For a chord, e.g. a simple major chord such as C major, which has notes C, E and G, you'll get 3 fundamentals + harmonics of each. Some of the harmonics from the different fundamentals will coincide (due to the almost rational integer ratio between the notes, which is what makes the chord sound "good"), however there will still be intervals between frequency components which are not just straight multiples, and it's the pattern of these that really determines the nature of the chord. It might be a good candidate for some kind of classifier or neural net.

Answer (score 1):

If it's sound like a chord to you, is because you brain is capable of distinguishing the harmonics of the chord.

So when you listen to a chord from a distance the string will be mixed together for the general note of the chord to be heard, that's like you are compressing the sound from many channels into one.

If you record in a good enough quality you should be able to split your sound into different thresholds determined by the notes you are trying to pick up, i.e drop-d, normal tuning.

Try to do the process in a sound editor before trying to tackle it as a program.

Answer (score 0):

You can find any single frequency of any instrument or even noise by using what's called a Fourier Transform.  It is a mathematical process in which frequency folding is performed in order to sort each and every tone in the sample you provide.  This is similar as to how scientists study the sun and other stars, looking at all the frequency information to see what elements are in what quantities.  In my master's thesis, I used what's called a FFT, or fast Fourier Transfer.

You can separate harmonics from pure tones, and much more with the FFT.  You will need to use many FFT iterations because you really can't wait for a FFT to decode 'Stairway to Heaven'.  Look locally at smaller snippets.

You can find software to do this for you at many places, and you can check out Wolfram Alpha and similar websites for apps and code to do this.